# Powershell - хранение списка объектов в файле

Tags: powershell, сериализация

Доброй ночи. Есть больше идеологический вопрос : оперирую в скрипте целым рядом значений, которые хотел бы хранить в файле, периодически поднимать, работать с ними, и сохранять вновь. 
То есть, я хочу создать объект с своими полями, собрать список их таких объектов, и иметь возможность сохранять этот список.
Попробую описать то, что мне требуется на c# :

```
public class MyObject { public string ID; public string Name; }
MyObject a = new MyObject() { ID="0x15", Name="Alex" };
MyCollections.Add(a);
MyCollections.DeserealizeToFile();
```

Исходя из кода, я хочу спросить :

1. Возможно ли создать в PoSH объект со своей структурой?
2. Возможно ли сложить такие объекты в List?
3. Что применяется для сериализации/десериализации?

Насколько вообще такой подход верный?

Перефразируя на Powershell :

```
# List для хранения
$MyList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList;
# Структура объекта
class Task 
{
   [string]$Name;
   [string]$ID;   
}
$a= [Task]::new();
$b= [Task]::new();
$a.ID = "654654";
$a.Name = "Viktor";
$b.Name = "Alex";
$MyList.Add($a);
$MyList.Add($b);
#Конвертация в JSON
$MyJson = ConvertTo-Json($MyList);
#Сохранение
$MyJson | Out-File d:\MyCollection.txt
```

Иначе говоря, есть коллекция своих объектов, которую можно крутить в foreach, и которую надо сохранять.

Приведенный выше код работает, но меня смущает необходимость промежуточной конвертации в JSON.

Второй вопрос - как десереализовать это обратно, в коллекцию?

Comment: добавь немного больше подробностей в вопрос. Начиная с PS3 есть возможность создавать объекты и добавлять им свойства, начиная с PS5 - можно классы создавать: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66693/2881286

Comment: Перефразировал на powershell

Comment: _меня смущает необходимость промежуточной конвертации в JSON_ - а что именно ты хотел в файл записать? Просто бинарное что-то?